# What was considered an epoch by the Phoenicians?

Tags: calendar, phoenicia

The Phoenicians used a lunisolar calendar similar to the Hebrew calendar. Do we have any idea about what Phoenicians considered as an epoch for their calendar, or at least about the nature of the said epoch (was it related to a religious event, a political one, astronomical, ...)?

Comment: What are you actually asking? Are you asking what was considered an epoch by the Phoenicians or are you asking, during which epoch/era was the Phoenician calendar used, or are you asking something else?

Comment: Thanks for the comment @Fred, I updated my question accordingly. I hope this clarifies its intent.

Answer (score 2):

You do not specify the time period, but in general the Phoenicians did not number years so they had no era. I do not, in fact, even know of any specific regnal years from Phoenician documents. Phoenician inscriptions only mention months and the names of rulers.

The most well known chronological document from ancient Phoenician culture is the [Gezer Calendar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gezer_calendar). This "calendar" is not a calendar at all, but is a very simple almanac which does not even give names to the months.